# Is there information in a spacy token indicative of the meaning of the token?

Tags: nlp, spacy

Suppose I have a spacy system and can easily mark a verb or punctuation member as having semantic meaning.

However, wherever possible I'd like to instead rely on native `spacy` information generated from the natural language processing pipeline.

---

For now, I have marked the following three items as semantic assignment operators *in my code* and rely on `spacy`'s branch head identification system (obtained via an entity's head.lefts or head.rights) to isolate the colon.  Then, I analyze the semantic meaning of the sentence with understanding that the lemma of the colon is in fact "be" or "list":

```
{ 'is', 'are', ':' }
```

However, I'd instead like to rely on some generic `spacy` linguistic information so that the system is less English-specific.

Is there any information, member, or property that will allow me to derive that the punctuation token is a semantic assignment operator?

For example, the verbs have the `.lemma_` property that indicates they are what I am characterizing as assignment operators (`.lemma_ = 'be'`) whereas the punctuation mark ':' *does register* as a token, but seems to have no indicative information as to its logical purpose.

Yet it is an explicit transitive operator, and it comes up almost 35% of the time a noun is given a state or membership in the technical prose I am analyzing.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. What do you mean that a punctuation token is a semantic assignment operator? Why would that be generic linguistic information? It may help to give an example sentence of the kind you work with. But I suspect the infromation you want just isn't there by default.

Comment: @polm23 I went ahead and answered my question.  No worries.

Answer (score 0):

I substituted textual colons with "is listed as" like so (the regex may not be correct under all circumstances):

```
re.sub(r'([A-z][.]?): ', r'\1 is listed as', text)
```

And spacy was able to process the sentence with the textual colon as a proper semantic token with a reasonably clear lemma.